# How to get access token from httpcontext using owin and Mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've got a IDP implemented in [IdentityServer 4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/). My web app client(implemented in Mvc 5) authenticates with the IDP but now I need to get the access token from the request.
A way to do that in .Net Core is to use the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTokenExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationtokenextensions) like so:

```
HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("acccess_token")
```

I would like to be able to do the same in my .net Mvc5 web app client but I can't find any nuget package or namespace that has a similar implementation. It is important to be able to do this in MVC5 and not .net Core. Anyone came across this before?

PS- Also worth to mention that I'm using OpenIdConnect

Comment: Were you able to solve using the answer below?

Comment: Sorry, But I've posted this question so long ago that I forgot which solution I chose.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The recently released [4.1.0 version of Katana](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/Roadmap#410-release-november-2019) now supports the [`SaveTokens` property](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/pull/297/files#diff-c3935a532c2daa1509a7dc4562e5dd59R313) (backported from ASP.NET Core).

In order to get the access token:

1. Update the [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/4.1.0) package to 4.1.0 (or newer)
2. Configure `SaveTokens` in your Startup class:

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    // Other options removed for readability
    SaveTokens = true,

    // Required for the authorization code flow to exchange for tokens automatically
    RedeemCode = true
});
```

3. Read the access token in your Controller:

```cs
var result = await Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies");
string token = result.Properties.Dictionary["access_token"];
```

Comment: Any suggestion as to why Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync might return null? Even with SaveTokens and RedeemCode set to true

Comment: @kape - will this work on .Net framework 4.7.1?. I've followed and set and above properties, still the middleware does not redeem code automatically. please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965137/automatic-code-authorization-code-redemption-using-latest-version-of-katana-d

Comment: +1 What a horrible convoluted way of accessing the access_token. A half dozen SO links, and more microsoft documentation than I can handle in one day and this is the solution I find to read the unencrypted access_token? Thank you! I need this to pass to the Graph API. This also works for HttpContext. `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies")`

Comment: Posting a link to the .NET CORE solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50623141/2567273

Comment: @Hos I found the solution. I think you as I make a typo in SignInAsAuthenticationType or AuthenticationType, because of it using "Cookies" didn't work.

Comment: first of all +1 for the solution.. this is not there in any MS documentation but worked like charm.... Now I am able to get access_token, id_token and refresh_token from 'GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Cookies")' but problem is how to get access_token issued and expiry time from same properties ? ExpireUtC gives Id token time... but is there any code which specificlly gices access_token expiry time?

Answer (score 0):

Inside *OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications* events the AutenticationTicket and its claims ready (there is no need to call userinfo endpoint).
In order to make that Ticket available (claimsprincipal) to the *httpcontext.current.user* do the following inside the *SecurityTokenValidated* event (*ReplaceIdentity* is just a custom extension method to replace the claims if exists an identity with same type):

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
{
    SecurityTokenValidated = (notification) =>
    {
        notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", notification.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
        notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", notification.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));
        
        notification.OwinContext.Authentication.User.ReplaceIdentity(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Achieve this result takes me three days of testing... but works excelent, you will have the User Identity available in HttpContext.Current.User with the other identities.