# ASP.NET Core 3.1: User.Identity.Name is empty in API Controller, but claim name is present

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4

I'm adding Identity Server to my existing project. Basically I have everything in place, but when I do a request to the API, the `User.Identity.Name` is null. However the `User.Identity.Claims` contains the name claim:

[image]

I'm aware of the way of getting the user name by `HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)`, but it would require a lot of code refactoring, so I'd rather avoid this way.

I configured the ApiResources in Identity server the following way:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources => new[]
{
    new ApiResource
    {
        Name = "my-api",
        DisplayName = "My API",
        Description = "My API",
        Scopes = new List<string> { "my-api"},
        UserClaims = new List<string> {
            JwtClaimTypes.Email,
            JwtClaimTypes.Name,
            JwtClaimTypes.Subject,
            JwtClaimTypes.Role,
        }
    }
};
```

and the client:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
    new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            // ...
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                "name",
                "roles",
                "my-api",
            }
        }
    };
```

Authentication setup in API project:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = config["IdentityServer:Domain"];

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = config["IdentityServer:Domain"],
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireClaim("scope", "my-api");
    });
});
```

Please advice what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Everything is wrong. You just have to use the recomended algorithm, not trying to invent your own that will never work without creating a new net framework for your algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean? I just copied the quickstart from IdentityServer repo and just adjusted it for my infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Microsoft and OpenID connect have different opinion on what the name of the "name" claim should be. So what you need to do is to tell the system what the name of the name claim is, by:

```
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        ...      
        opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        ...
    }
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging JwtBearer Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/)