# Micorosf Entra IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'System.Text.StringBuilder'

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm trying to implement Azure AD authentication with an ASP NET app using Owin.

The code i'm using is the following:

```
           app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId,
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    }

                }
            );
```

I'm getting below error: `IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'System.Text.StringBuilder'`

I checked the token and it has the kid. According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/signing-key-rollover, NET OWIN OpenID Connect already has the necessary logic to handle key rollover automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'System.Text.StringBuilder'` signifies that the JSON Web Token (JWT) being validated lacks a `kid` (key identifier) claim, which is essential for identifying the key used to sign the JWT.

To resolve this issue, you can employ the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` class, which features a `SecurityTokenValidated` event triggered after token validation. Within the event handler, you have the opportunity to augment the identity with additional claims, such as the `ClaimTypes.Name` claim.

```cs
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
  new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
      {
          ClientId = clientId,
          Authority = authority,
          PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
           Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
           {
            SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
             {
               string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
         });
                 
 }
```

**Make Sure you have installed below packages**

```cs
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin  
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect  
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies  
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb  
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions  
Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: still not working with same error. SecurityTokenValidated is never called

Comment: Can you Check the authentication logs to see if the incoming request is authenticated. If the request is not authenticated, then SecurityTokenValidated will not be called.

Comment: the authentication request is successfull based on Azure logs. The IdToken i receive has the kid. {
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "pYWnqQpUBsDL2b3CzhPofxwYvr8"
} in the header section

Comment: can you share github link to your code?

Comment: I will do.
Hope this refernce [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68680330/microsoft-openidconnect-owin-response) helps you

Comment: problem solved. i had to configure a new application on Azure and it just worked